# Error al compilar en modo AOT en Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

Recien estoy corrigiendo algunas cosas en el proyecto por lo que decidí pasar de compilación JIT a AOT para ir corrgiendo algunos fallos en el proyecto y tengo un problema en un objeto al generar la compilación, dicho objeto lo recibó desde un @input

```
@Input() paymentReference: PaymentReferenceWithParameters[] = [];
```

ahora desde el front lo utilizo de la siguiente manera

```
  <span>{{ paymentReference.reference.creationDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>
  <span>{{ paymentReference.reference.paydayLimit | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>
  <span>{{paymentReference.reference.paymentReferenceInstallment.installmentNumber}}</span>
```

El problema es que no me esta detectando paymentReference.reference

```
export interface PaymentReferenceWithParameters {
  reference: PaymetReference;
  parameters: ParameterDistribution[];
}

export interface PaymetReference {
  referenceNumber?: string;
  referenceType?: any;
  value: number;
  paydayLimit?: any;
  creationDate?: any;
  paymentReferenceInstallment?: PaymentReferenceInstallment;
  active?: boolean;
  contractNumber?: string;
  documentNumber?: string;
}
```

Al generar la compilacion "ng build --configuration produccion"

```
"configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "4mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            },
```

pero recibo este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como mencioné funciona bien al ejecutar el problema es al compilar por AOT a alguien le ha pasado por lo mismo quizas?

Gracias.

Comment: La variable `@Input() paymentReference` es un arreglo y lo usas como si fuera un objeto individual.

Comment: @Lobos mil gracias tienes toda la razón

Comment: debes colocar a partir de angular 9 la propiedad aot : false

Comment: No necesariamente. Depende de lo que se use y si alguna dependencia tiene líos con ello.

Comment: Si el comentario de @CarlosRuiz resolvió el problema, pónganlo como respuesta para que puedan aceptarlo ;)